# writing console log to file up to a certain size

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have some code that's outputing **A LOT** of `console.log` lines. as of now I've been running it like this: `node index.js > output.txt` however, this isn't enough anymore since after a few hours the file becomes WAY too big to open in most editors.

Whats a better way to handle constant log creation in node? Is there a way to create a new log (with like `output<TIMESTAMP>.txt`) that would be created once the previous file reaches X size?

Comment: you can do it with fs module. `fs = require("fs")`

Comment: using fs you can do log rotation like @nilobarp suggested within your current script without having to pass your scripts output to another. The best way would to write your own logging module and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your logs to a `script` rather than a file and handle the stream within your script for log rotation.

A good starting point is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231486/how-to-implement-logrotate-in-shell-script